# How to workaround using a PEG parser to parse an HTTP request

Tags: algorithm, http, parsing, streaming, peg

So from [my understanding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-5), HTTP requests can be provided responses *before* the server is even done reading the complete request, such as in this case:

> Upon receiving a request which includes an Expect request-header
> field with the "100-continue" expectation, an origin server MUST
> either respond with 100 (Continue) status and continue to read
> from the input stream, or respond with a final status code. The
> origin server MUST NOT wait for the request body before sending
> the 100 (Continue) response.

This means that, theoretically, the server can read just the protocol/version number and maybe the first header or two and determine whether or not to continue reading the request. Or it can take just that first bit of information and start sending a response immediately.

Well, I am in love with PEG grammars for their ease of understanding and simplicity to construct. However, a PEG grammar parses using **recursive decent** from what I have learned, which means it goes like "is this an HTTP request?... is this an HTTP header *list*?... is this an HTTP header?... is this an HTTP header *name*?... is this a double quote?... etc." It might get done with the header list and then move onto the body, but it is still *in the context of the HTTP request as a whole*. So it's only done after the whole request is parsed.

My question is how can you use a grammar defined *like* a PEG, but in a different way somehow so it can handle this streaming situation? Would it simply make sense to emit events during parsing, so when it is done with each Header it emits that header? But then what if the body is malformed, then the whole parse will fail, and so we'd need to say "cancel our earlier header handling code". But wouldn't you need to do this anyways with a non-recursive-descent parser, where say you respond with the "continue" stuff initially, but then it fails, you then rewrite the status to say "error 404" or whatever. How does that work? And how can I conceptualize how the grammar should be used in a parser to handle this streaming case?

Side note: I do not want to write a custom manual HTTP parser. Not because it's hard but because it's ugly. The requirements for this project are that the HTTP parsing be done using an HTTP grammar (of at least *some* sort).

Comment: PEGs are usually intended to parse the whole input unfortunately.